# MySQL JSON Encode Data

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json, mysqli

So, I have this PHP file which echos the data as JSON:

This is here is the PHP:

```
// Recieved the user id:
$userId = $_POST['userId'];

// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect("123.com", "123", "123", "123", "1234");


// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to database " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Work with the database to grab user statistics..
$getQuizMode      = "SELECT `QuizModeScore` FROM `userstats` WHERE UserId = $userId";
$getChallengeMode = "SELECT `ChallengeModeScore` FROM `userstats` WHERE UserId = $userId";

$quizModeData      = mysqli_query($con, $getQuizMode);
$challengeModeData = mysqli_query($con, $getChallengeMode);

// Build the response
$arr = array('Quiz' => $quizModeData, 'Challenge' => $challengeModeData);

// echo the json back:
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Now here is my client-side javascript:

```
var variableToSend = "109607962907537440488";

$.post('manageUserStats.php', {userId: variableToSend}, function(data){
    console.log("Got these user stats: ", data);
});
```

When I see the console I see that this is logged:

```
Got these user stats:  {"Quiz":{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null},"Challenge":{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}}
```

However, I want to get the data that is pictured here:

[image: Stuff]

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I just get these two numbers?

Comment: You don't do anything with the data once you fetch it. Look in to [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) to pull the data from the result resources.  Also, you don't sanitize your input so you are open to SQL injection, and you should move away from `mysql_` functions. ^^

Comment: Hint: Start with one query / value. Get it to work. Then add the second query. Hint2: Use the OO interface of mysqli.

Comment: Hint #3, both your results are from the same table with the same Id, select them both in one query and don't waste the resources of doing a second query.

Comment: echo back the posted userId and see if this is correct. Make sure that the columns are correctly spelled in the query.
Obviously the query does not return the results.

Comment: @Daniel Incorrect, look at the code, and look at the comments and answer so far.  Don't point OP in the wrong direction.

Comment: @Jon - Yep, you're right. You already pointed out more specific where to look. :). Might as well post it as answer.

Comment: @Daniel I did, with a PDO example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get what you have working, use:

```
$getQuiz = "SELECT QuizModeScore, ChallengeModeScore FROM userstats WHERE UserId = $userId";

$res = mysqli_query($con, $getQuiz);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
$quizModeData = $row['QuizModeScore'];
$challengeModeData = $row['ChallengeModeScore'];
```

Instead of:

```
$getQuizMode      = "SELECT `QuizModeScore` FROM `userstats` WHERE UserId = $userId";
$getChallengeMode = "SELECT `ChallengeModeScore` FROM `userstats` WHERE UserId = $userId";

$quizModeData      = mysqli_query($con, $getQuizMode);
$challengeModeData = mysqli_query($con, $getChallengeMode);
```

Also, you should validate `$_POST['userId']` before using it in the query. I would suggest PDO because mysqli is a pain to get working when you parametrize thogh.

**EDIT**

To use as PDO, look at how to [create a PDO object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) and then use the following assuming that `$pdo` is the name of the variable you used to construct `PDO`.

```
$query = "SELECT QuizModeScore, ChallengeModeScore FROM userstats WHERE UserId = ?";
$st = $pdo->prepare($query);
$st->execute(array($userId));
$row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$quizModeData = $row['QuizModeScore'];
$challengeModeData = $row['ChallengeModeScore'];
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! I'm going to look into this PDO thing, but for now I'm just a beginner! Thanks.

Comment: @Cygwinnian You're welcome!  If you are just a beginner, then you should start using PDO now so you don't have to break any bad habits.  A [decent tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) on using PDO can help. ^^

Comment: @Cygwinnian - Might as well start with that asap. PDO takes over the sanitizing part and is safer to use. I can recommend this tube to start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dF8hoPj-1bc . Sit back and watch the show :)